# How to print attribute accessor value when attribute accessor has same name as method

Tags: ruby

I have a class `Book` with an instance variable `title` and a method `title`

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
  def title(title)
    @title = title.capitalize
  end
end
```

I create a book object

```
b = Book.new
```

And then I set the title

```
b.title("inferno")
```

Now when I try to print the title field variable value

```
p b.title
```

Ruby thinks I'm trying to call the method

> "title": wrong number of arguments

Any idea how to print the field variable value?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `attr_accessor :title` does is create wrapper methods, identical to `def title()` and `def title=(value)`. It's just a syntactic sugar method generation. You can then set the value with:

```
b.title = "Whatever"
```

and access with:

```
b.title
```

If you just wanted a reader or a writer, you could use `attr_reader :title` or `attr_writer :title` separately.

If you want to make your own reader/writer methods manually, all the above do is create:

```
def title
  @title
end

def title=(value)
  @title = value
end
```

You can't have two methods with the same name and different arity in Ruby, so when you define your own method (as in your question), you're overwriting the reader method with your writer. That leaves you with two ways to set and no way to read.

You could use `attr_reader` and a custom writer:

```
def title=(value)
  @title = value.capitalize
end
```

You can always name the method anything you want, like `def capitalize_and_set_title(value)`. It might be more clear than the magic of `attr_accessor` and operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want in order to set the title is:

```
def title=(str)
  super str.try(:capitalize)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to set the value with `title(some_value)` and read it with `title` (without arguments), you could do e.g.:

```
class Book
  def title(title = :no_value_given)
    if title == :no_value_given
      @title
    else
      @title = title.capitalize
    end
  end
end
```

This relies on a default argument value for when you call it without arguments.

The reason I did not use `nil` as a default argument value is so that you can set the value to `nil`.